# Vibrate phone when button is pressed

Tags: ios

I am trying to vibrate an iPhone when the user has clicked a button in swift, i am using the AudioToolbox and this is what i have so far.

```
  @IBAction func Vibrate(sender: UIButton) {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
}
```

Can anyone can give me a hand on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: And what's your question? Is it not working? How?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

 }
}
```

Comment: ......when pressing a button is in the title??? Not viewDidLoad. Also OP stated they are using AudioToolBox already